# Why does yum install python3 install python3.6

Tags: python, linux, yum

I have noticed that `yum install python3` or `apt-get install python3` python `3.6` but I am unable to understand why it installs this specific version; `3.8` is the latest version of python. Why does it pick `3.6` in specific ?

Comment: the version of the distribution you're running has chosen that version of python3.  my `apt-get` installs python3.8 for example (ubuntu:focal)

Comment: In addition, if you want an up to date or specific version of python, you can use tools like [conda](https://conda.io) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just depends on the OS you are using. Each OS packages a certain version of python and sticks with it. For example:

- CentOS 7: python 3.6
- CentOS 8: python 3.6
- Ubuntu 16.04: python 3.5
- Ubuntu 18.04: python 3.6
- Ubuntu 20.04: python 3.8

NOTE: There are some OS that use rolling releases and that thus will update their default python version, but that is more rare.